# getting error from taquito while trying to access rpc url of smartpy

Tags: taquito

I am trying to access a URL
url: 'https://mainnet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT……

But it throws an error
 HttpResponse: Http error response: (503) 503 Service Unavailable

No server is available to handle this request.

at HttpBackend. (/app/node_modules/@taquito/http-utils/dist/taquito-http-utils.umd.js:480:31)

at rejected (/app/node_modules/@taquito/http-utils/dist/taquito-http-utils.umd.js:30:69)

What is this error about and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

try another node, there are lists available:

- https://tzcomet.io/#/settings
- https://cotezos.github.io/teznodes/

Comment: will the data structure be same on each node or will that be different on different node?

Comment: the same, as long as the node is synced, which can be checked with /monitor/bootstrapped (https://tezos.gitlab.io/shell/rpc.html#get-monitor-bootstrapped)

Answer (score 0):

https://mainnet.smartpy.io/ results in a 404 and is not a supported endpoint.
You can find a list of community-supported endpoints here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/rpc_nodes/